# Windows file explorer crashes while searching a certain term in the search bar

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, crash, search

While searching for a file named "advance" in a network drive, the file explorer crashes and closes automatically. This happens only when the search reaches a particular folder in the directory which contains so many files and folders. I have done the search on the said folder and now it crashes when the search term reaches "ad". **I tried other search terms which works fine**. And everything works fine outside this folder.

What I believe is happening, **when the search reaches a certain file the file explorer crashes**. Please help

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Forgot to mention that I did all the `chkdsk`, `sfc /scannow` with no use. Also did all the virsus, malware and spyware scan and clean with no use.

And used [Autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to disable all contextMenuHandlers(basically unchecking all)

Comment: Start by running a disk/filesystem scan (`chkdsk` from an admin command prompt) and see if it reports any problems.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 the resul to `chkdsk` is : _Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems. No further action is required._. And I have done all the sfc /scannow and virus and malware scans

Comment: How much memory is in your system? My guess is that file explorer is trying to allocate to much memory when it reaches the folder containing a lot of files.

Comment: @Ouroborus memory is not at all the problem. The PC got 16GB memory and there is enough free memory. There are other directories with lot of files does the search seamlessly.

Comment: create a crash dump and share it so that I can debug it: http://pastebin.com/WACz5GBU

Comment: @magicandre1981 I have created a crash dump using [this method](https://helgeklein.com/support/creating-an-application-crash-dump/) and can upload that on Monday. But if want me to run your method, need more time coz it's a client machine and there are procedures to follow.

Comment: my .reg files configure the same settings like your guide. Submit the dmp to my Dropbox so that only me can look at the dump: https://www.dropbox.com/request/krlQVF6raslWp8MVIB98

Comment: @magicandre1981 I have uploaded the dump file to dropbox. Thanks

Comment: I saw the dmp. You get a HEAP_CORRUPTION. you need to import this .reg file to get better dumps: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtziW2MYxY8SglqCKUAszY8GAaE4. **ATTENTION**, please download a 3rd party file management tool like Salamander to have a file explorer, the new settings trigger Explorer crashes much faster becasue . After you have generated a new dump, import this to disable the dump creation: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtziW2MYxY8ShSBS080oymdSDtx_

Comment: have you created the new dump?

Comment: sorry @magicandre1981 waiting for approval from the client. will update as soon as I get the dump

Comment: ok, come back if you got the new dump